# HTML Wireframes/Mockups for Web, Android, iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, mockups

Is there a HTML/Javascript/CSS framework that can do what the fancy mocking tools do with minimal work from a Text Editor.

I have just been evaluating various online mockup tools

Examples

- pidoco.com
- balsamiq.com
- mockflow

I think I would prefer to do this straight in HTML but I want some flexibility.

- Apply simple text controls (Standard HTML will do DropDown, TextBox, Radio Button)
- Apply device targeted themes (iPhone, Android, Web)
- Give it some effects (Typography, 3D, Boxes)
- Easy Layout system, like 960.gs

Comment: Why is it the wrong place, I'm after a Javascript or HTML framework that does something similar to Mockup Tools.

Comment: Currently found a framework called getwirefy.com which is pretty good, does anyone know of other frameworks similar to this

Answer (score 0):

try Moqups

1. [Moqups](https://moqups.com/) : online vector based wireframing tool
2. [mocking bird](https://gomockingbird.com/)